# Upgrading Server 2003sp2 to Server 2003 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-server-2003-r2

I have upgraded my AD schema to the 2003R2 level in order to support DFS replication via this guide: http://www.happysysadm.com/2011/10/windows-2003-extending-schema-to-r2-for.html

I am interested in completing the 2003R2 installation.  I have volume licenses for every windows server available except 2012.  Three for 2003r2 x32 and three for 2003r2 x64.  NONE of these keys work in the 2003R2 setup wizard.

Which product/edition/variation/wildcard/etc/etc key do I need to put into this?  Is there some way to find out what edition key it is looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't upgrade to 2003 R2.  You're over 5 years late to that party.  These days, upgrade to at least 2008 R2, or don't bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key type expected is dependent on the media you're installing from.  Retail media expects a retail-series key, volume licensed media expects a volume license key, MSDN/Technet issued media expects an MSDN-series key, and so on.

Since you have Volume License keys, you should have access to the [Microsoft Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx), where, as horrific as the thought is, you can still download Server 2003 R2 install media ISOs to match your VLKs.

[image]

Of course, like I said in the comment, don't upgrade to Server 2003 R2 this late in the game.  Upgrade/migrate to at least Server 2008 R2, or don't bother.

Comment: Got it thank you.  The download is no longer available via VLSC, so I took a CD I found and burned an ISO from that.

Comment: And that CD I took an ISO from had a key with it, which was the same as a VLK listed in VLSC but doesn't work.  (it was hand written though)